# Problems copying files with spaces inside the file name in a bash script

Tags: shell-script

I have the following function inside a BASH script (running under Ubuntu 12.x), which would copy over a file with spaces inside the file name. It's not working. I've tried many different combinations, with "', with \", etc. How do I get this to work? Thanks!

```sh
function copy_docs()
{
    source_directory=/mnt/someplace
    release_directory=/doc/someotherplace

    cp ${source_directory}/"Some file with spaces.txt" ${release_directory}/

}
```

This is what I'm getting as output (from nearly all permutations):

```
cp: cannot stat `/mnt/someplace/some': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `file': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `with': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `spaces': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try `cp ${source_directory}/"Some\ file\ with\ spaces.txt" ${release_directory}/`

Comment: Do either of your directories have spaces in their names?

Comment: That did not work.

It separates the file into 4 different files, attempting to copy four files (i.e. "Some", "file", "with", "spaces").

Comment: I don't see why that should not work. Try running it like this, and post your results: `set -x; copy_docs; set +x`

Comment: Your output `cp: cannot stat /mnt/someplace/some: No such file or directory` does not match the file name in your `cp` statement.  `"Some file with spaces.txt"` is not the same as `"some file with spaces.txt"` which is what your output suggests you are attempting to copy.

Comment: Since you haven't given consistent data that would tell us what you're doing, I'm closing this question as a duplicate of our generic question on handling file names with spaces (it was that or “unclear what you're asking”). Read that thread. If you still don't understand why your attempt doesn't work, we can reopen this question, but you must tell us what you're actually doing. Copy-paste your code, the way you invoke is, and the error message.

Answer (score 2):

```
cp ${source_directory}/Some\ file\ with\ spaces.txt ${release_directory}/
```

or

```
cp ${source_directory}/'Some file with spaces.txt' ${release_directory}/
```

Comment: Neither of those worked.

Comment: Have you read Timothy Martin's comment posted after your edit? Are you sure there is "Some", not "some"? If yes then add `bash --version` and `type cp` to your question.